# How can I get the object when validated, in the clean function?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to get an object by slug field in order to check the difference between the number of items sold and purchased.

But I get the error:

```
'NewDateSell' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

How can I make this check differently?

```
class NewDateSell(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        sell_now = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
        item = Item.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

        if item.item_remainder - sell_now < 0:
            raise ValidationError('The number of items sold must not exceed the number of items purchased')

        return sell_now

    class Meta:
        model=Sales
        fields=('date','quantity','price')
        widgets = {
           'date': DateInput(),
        }
```

File `models.py`:

```
    class Sales(models.Model):
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
        date = models.DateField()
        quantity = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000000)])
        price = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10000000)],)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('item-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.item.slug,})
```

File `views.py`:

```
class SellPage(CreateView):
    model=Sales
    template_name="market/new_date_sell.html"
    form_class=NewDateSell

    def form_valid(self, form):
        item=Item.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.item=item
        item.sell_items+=int(self.request.POST['quantity']) 
        item.total_sell_profit+=float(self.request.POST['price'])
        item.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: can you add models to your questions and Meta of `NewDateSell`

Comment: @daniherrera, 'NewDateSell' object has no attribute 'slug'

Comment: try `self.instance.slug`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, Not, not the slug field, but the link of the current page)

Comment: ModelForm doesn't store information about current page, you should add it as a parameter when create form. If you add more code where you create form it will be easier to help you

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, 
I have a slug field, in the Item model, this is the related model. But it is added after validation

Comment: @AndreyMaslov, 
Please tell me how can I add as a parameter? If I have a class and not a function

Comment: @Salivanch did you add `model = ...` to the `Meta` of your `NewDateSell`? It is not in the code from the question.

Comment: @Ralf, 
Thank. I hurried something and sent something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add slug as a parameter to your ModelForm. also your clean method should return dict not a single value

```
class NewDateSell(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = kwargs.pop("slug")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean() 
        sell_now = cleaned_data.get('quantity')
        item = Item.objects.get(slug=self.slug)
            if item.item_remainder - sell_now < 0:
            raise ValidationError('The number of items sold must not exceed the number of items purchased')
        cleaned_data["sell_now"] = sell_now
        cleaned_data["item"] = item
        return cleaned_data
```

and in `view.py` if you use GenericViews we will provide additional parameter to our form in `get_form_kwargs`

```
class SellPage(CreateView):
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["slug"] = self.kwargs['slug']
        return kwargs
    ...
```

Comment: In views.py, I do this all in the class, inheriting from CreateView, I need to write NewDateSell (request.POST ...)  in form_class?

Comment: show code in your views.py and i will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you suggest some resources for learning django?)

Comment: official documentation:)